# What is the purpose of keeping "open" a merged MR in Gitlab?

Tags: git, source-code, gitflow, gitlab

In gitlab, there is Merge Requests (MR) like in github there is Pull Requests (PR).

If the MR is rejected, sure, we close it.

But what if the MR is merged ? In that case the button to close the MR stay available.

So, what is the right way ? Should we close all MR at the end of the story ? And if so, when to close it ?

What is the purpose of keeping "open" a merged MR ?

### EDIT

Gitlab team respond me on tweeter that

> The 'Close' button is not available on 'Merged' merge requests. If you see this behavior, something weird is happening.
>
> https://twitter.com/gitlab/status/775695644845608960

I responded

> Though I get it for all of my merged MR like on this screenshot ..so I'm confused..
>
> https://twitter.com/gitlab/status/775695644845608960

Adding this screenshot:

[image]

So, I'm again trying to understand this situation..

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine a few reasons why merging and closing might be separate.

Maybe your merge is part of a larger feature and you want to perform other merges before you close them all.  Maybe there's a merge conflict, and you have to resolve it.  There might be a dozen possible actions you could take *before* you close.  A reject is a whole different story; there is nothing else to do.

Basically, they are separate operations for the same reasons the save button and close buttons are different operations in your favorite word processor.

Comment: Do you really think about other examples ? Because : (1) once merged, performing other merges will require to create new merge-requests, and (2) If there is any conflict, accepting the MR is not possible (button disabled) until they are resolved by new commits. I only see one opération that could be done between merging and closing, posting comments. Or edit labels, and other MR properties.